# Dart - Detects when in a list there is a 'false' with a 'true' in the next index

Tags: list, dart, for-loop, boolean

I would like to create a script in Dart that detects when in the OutputBool2 list there is a 'false' with a 'true' in the next index

I created this script, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
List OutputIndex2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23];
List OutpuBool2 = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false];


for (int j in OutputIndex2.sublist(0, OutputList2.length - 1)) {
      print(j);

      if (OutputBool2[j] == false && OutputList2[j + 1] == true) {
        print(FIND!!);

      }
    }
```

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks :)

Comment: What **exactly** does "doesn't seem to work" mean? Also, I don't know dart, but can you really print strings without quoting them? Shouldn't there be something like `print('FIND!!');` with the quotes? In general, when you think you've done something wrong, *always* describe **why** you think that. Do you get an error? No result? The wrong result?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanks for the answer, I mean that in the OutputBool2 list there are some 'false' and 'true' nearby, but it doesn't print 'FIND !!' ... now I will update the question ...

Comment: Your bug is that you check `OutputList[j + 1] == true` and not `OutputBool2[j + 1]`.  `OutputList` seems unnecessary and just increases the likelihood for confusion.  Additionally, checking `== false` and `== true` is a code smell: just use `!OutputBool[j] && OutputBool[j + 1]`.  Note that removing those redundant checks would have caught the mistake about accidentally using `OutputList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this code:

```
List<bool> OutpuBool2 = [
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    true,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    true,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < OutpuBool2.length; i++) {
    if (OutpuBool2[i] == false) {
      if (OutpuBool2[i + 1] == true) {
        print('There is a false with a true in the next index in index: $i');
      }
    }
  }
```

and this is the result:
There is a false with a true in the next index in index: 6
There is a false with a true in the next index in index: 11

is that what you meant?

Comment: yes, thank you for your answer, that is perfect, i only suggest to add - 1 in "i < OutputBool2.length - 1"

Comment: you can put (!OutpuBool2[i]) instead of (OutpuBool2[i] == false) and (OutpuBool2[i+1]) instead of (OutpuBool2[i + 1] == true)